# search for element within element by tagname

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

After being stuck for a few hours on this problem, i think it is time for call for help on this.

### Situation

I have a XML file which i need to filter and group. I've managed to filter it with the `:Contains` part. I've also determined the nodes on which i need to group (the `getGroups` function gives those back to me). Now i want to create a new XML with the filtered values and grouped by the returned keys.

### Code

```
var XMLElement = document.createElement("DataElementsCalc");
jQuery(xml).find("DataElements " + topNodes + filter).each( function() {
    var dataSetTemp = this.parentNode;

    if(calculation1 != "")
    {
        var groupKeys = getGroups(dataSetTemp,calculation1);
        var tempXML = XMLElement;
        jQuery(groupKeys).each(function (key,value) {
            var tempValue = 'a' + value.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '');
            if(tempXML.getElementsByTagName(tempValue).length > 0)
            {
                tempXML = tempXML.getElementsByTagName(tempValue);
            }
            else
            {
                var Node = document.createElement(tempValue);
                tempXML.appendChild(Node);
                tempXML = Node;
            }
        });

        var Node = document.createElement("InfoSet");
        var x = dataSetTemp.childNodes;
        for (i=0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            if(x[i].nodeType == 1)
            {
                var tempElement = document.createElement(x[i].nodeName);
                tempElement.innerHTML = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                Node.appendChild(tempElement);
            }
        }
        tempXML.appendChild(Node);
    }
});
```

### Explanation

As said in the situation, i already filtered the XML and have the groupNames from the `getGroups` function. There are a few other things i need to explain for this code:

- `tempValue` is being build as a `a + value.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '');`. This is being done because i possible get dates into the groupKeys. This way the node name is getting a working name (i received errors on other ways).
- I want to create a new XML which is leveled by the groups. If a group already exists, i want to create a new element in it, not get a new group with the same name. (my problem at the moment).

### Problem

As mentioned above, the groups aren't checked properly. Firstly: `tempXML.getElementsByTagName(tempValue).length` returns the error that the function `tempXML.getElementsByTagName` does not exists. Secondly: If i change this to `document.getElemetsByTagName` I get a lot of the same nodes in my XML file.

### Effect

The grouping effect doesn't work as it should. I get OR an error, OR a lot of the same nodes in my `DataElementsCalc`.

### Questions

How can i solve this? How do create nodes beneath specific nodes (for if there is a group A beneath group 1 as well as beneath group 2)?

### Tried

Change `tempXML` to `document` on different places (all getElementsByTagName, at the same time or not). Looked for another way to create a XML which is easier to handle (haven't found one, yet)

Comment: Since you use jQuery, change all your code to jQuery. It'd be far less lines and easier to debug etc.

Comment: @LShetty I can try to do that, but as i see now, it will make my task a lot harder. The part of adding an element in jquery is immediately an append. Now at least it looks like a generic element. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: jQuery is nothing but javascript. Both work exatcly the same way!

Comment: I know JQuery is nothing but javascript, but is it also the other way around? Can i do everything with JQuery i can do with Javascript. For example, as i understood when an element is created, in JQuery i immediatly need to set a location where to put it. As far as i can see, i didn't do this in my code. I also don't see anything in the source code for this (maybe this is the reason why it doesn't work??) @LShetty

Comment: _when an element is created, in JQuery i immediatly need to set a location where to put it._ No, it doesn't need to! `var $elem = $("<div/>")` would create a div. You can append it later when you're ready to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by myself in the comments of the question:

> I also don't see anything in the source code for this (maybe this is the reason why it doesn't work??)

I tried to place the `XMLElement` into an existing element on my webpage (like this:

```
var XMLElement = document.createElement("DataElementsCalc");
jQuery('.basicData').append(XMLElement);
```

in which basicData is a class of an existing element).

Now i do get a list of all elements ordered on the groups i wanted.

### Final version

```
var XMLElement = jQuery("<DataElementsCalc/>");
jQuery('.basicData').append(XMLElement);
jQuery(xml).find("DataElements " + topNodes + filter).each( function()
{
    aantalElementsTotal++;
    var dataSetTemp = this.parentNode;

    if(calculation1 != "")
    {
        var groupKeys = getGroups(dataSetTemp,calculation1);
        var tempXML = XMLElement;
        var groupId = '';
        jQuery(groupKeys).each(function (key,value) {
            var tempValue = 'a' + value.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '');
            groupId += 'a' + value.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '');
            if(jQuery("#" + groupId).length > 0)
            {
                tempXML = jQuery("#" + groupId);
            }
            else
            {
                var Node = jQuery("<"+tempValue+"/>");
                jQuery(Node).attr('id', groupId);
                jQuery(tempXML).append(Node);
                tempXML = Node;
            }
        });

        var Node = jQuery("<InfoSet/>");
        var x = dataSetTemp.childNodes;
        for (i=0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            if(x[i].nodeType == 1)
            {
                var tempElement = jQuery("<"+x[i].nodeName+"/>");
                jQuery(tempElement).text(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                jQuery(Node).append(tempElement);
            }
        }
        jQuery(tempXML).append(Node);
    }
});
```

Comment: Something is going not as it should. This script works perfectly in Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox or Internet Explorer. Don't know why, but it fails on on the last part: the addition of the tempelement to Node (for only 1 specific node).